# is it possible to capture per application sound streams and then use these as recording devices?

Tags: audio, voip, discord

i was just wondering if there exists an application nowadays that can capture an applications output (not system wide audio) and then assign it to a "virtual" recording device which i would then use in applications like discord, zoom etc.

all the answers i seem to find are from several years ago, and this question is difficult to word so it's worded differently from person to person.

something like this must exist though since discord can capture per app audio with it's share screen function.

Comment: You need to ask this on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - but tell them what OS